# R - No peaks appearing in my bedgraph Sushi plot

Tags: r, windows

I have used the following code:
`library('Sushi')

```
# Import dataset to R
chrom = "chr3"
chromstart = 189349216
chromend = 189615068
# Plot bedgragh 
plotBedgraph(Test_bedgraph,chrom,chromstart,chromend,colorbycol= 
SushiColors(5))
# Label genome 
labelgenome(chrom,chromstart,chromend,n=4,scale="Mb")
# Label y axis
mtext("Read depth",side=2,line=3,cex=1,font=2)
axis(side=2,las=2,tcl=.2)`
```

to plot CHIP-seq data from UCSC but no peaks appear. To rule out the type of data used (broadpeak, narrowpeak) and if it's specific to the region l'm looking at, l've imported different peak data on other regions and it still ends up plotting no peaks. Example below of my original region (without peaks): 
[image]

The code l used above is straight from the 'Sushi' package documentation. How do l fix this so l can make plots like this (with peaks):
[image]

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your bedgraph file, but without knowing what it looks like its hard to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows:

Make sure your bedgraph file can be read  by R / RStudio

> A <- read.delim("Test.begraph")
>   head(A)
>
> ## The output should look something as follow (in the form of a matrix!) and will be specific to your bedgraph, i.e. for chr3 )
>
> chrom chromstart chromend value
>   1 chr12    3025780  3025963   0.5
>   2 chr12    3098218  3098548   0.5
>   3 chr12    3188951  3189233   0.5
>   4 chr12    3209257  3209490   0.5
>   5 chr12    3210230  3210483   0.5
>   6 chr12    3235648  3235987   0.5
>
> ## Then try the following code:
>
> plotBedgraph(A,chrom,chromstart,chromend,transparency=.50,flip=FALSE,color="blue",linecol="blue")

The "flip=FALSE" is what I always use since I plot bedgraph files for two DNA binding proteins on the same graph! It would be optional, but If you too decide to plot your ChIPseq data for two factors on the same plot for comparison, then you'll need it and rescale the second plot to match the first. The rescaling code is shown in the link below under "Usage":
https://rdrr.io/bioc/Sushi/src/R/plotBedgraph.R

Hope it helps!